# Tidy: aggregate by group while excluding nested subgroup from each row

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm wanting to use max and min to see which subgroups of a larger group are clearly less than the rest within that particular larger group.

That's horribly wordy, so a couple examples:

```
  x <- read.csv(text = 'grp,subgrp,num
              1,1,2
              1,1,3
              1,2,4
              1,2,6
              1,2,7
              2,3,7
              2,4,6
              2,4,7,
              2,5,7')
```

Within group 1, subgroup 1 is clearly less than subgroup 2 since max(2,3) < min(4,6,7).
Within group 2, subgroup 3 and 4 are not clearly less or more than the other since max(7) from subgroup 3 and 5 is not less than min(6,7), and max(6,7) is not less than 7.

I can easily get a group max/min, and a subgroup max/min, but if I could get a group max/min that discludes the subgroup for each row (like dplyr::mutate), then I could easily compare the subgroup max with the group+disclude subgroup min. Just like in the examples.

The key variable I can't figure out is mingrpexclsubgrp, and the entire result would look like:

```
  x <- read.csv(text = 'grp,subgrp,num,maxsubgrp,mingrpexclsubgrp,isless
                1,1,2,3,4,T
                1,1,3,3,4,T
                1,2,4,7,2,F
                1,2,6,7,2,F
                1,2,7,7,2,F
                2,3,7,7,6,F
                2,4,6,7,7,F
                2,4,7,7,7,F
                2,5,7,7,6,F')
```

maxsubgroup is:

```
x %>%
group_by(subgrp) %>%
mutate(maxsubgrp = max(num))
```

And isless would be:

```
x %>%
mutate(isless = maxsubgrp < mingrpexclsubgrp)
```

A base R solution could be based off of this with the correct merging, but I'm hoping for a tidy and/or vectorized version.

```
for(i in unique(x$grp)){
  y <- x[x$grp == i, ]
  for(j in unique(y$subgrp)){
    print(paste(i,j))
    print(min(x$num[x$grp == i & x$subgrp != j]))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(x)[, {          
      sg <- .SD[['subgrp']]
      nm <- .SD[['num']]
        setnames(.SD[, .(max(num), min(nm[sg != subgrp])), subgrp],
                  2:3, c('maxsubgrp', 'mingrpexclsubgrp'))
        }, by = grp
        ][x, on = .(grp, subgrp)
         ][ , isless := maxsubgrp < mingrpexclsubgrp][]
#  grp subgrp maxsubgrp mingrpexclsubgrp num isless
#1:   1      1         3                4   2   TRUE
#2:   1      1         3                4   3   TRUE
#3:   1      2         7                2   4  FALSE
#4:   1      2         7                2   6  FALSE
#5:   1      2         7                2   7  FALSE
#6:   2      3         7                6   7  FALSE
#7:   2      4         7                7   6  FALSE
#8:   2      4         7                7   7  FALSE
#9:   2      5         7                6   7  FALSE
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
x %>% 
   split(.$grp, .$subgrp, drop = TRUE) %>%
   map_df(~ 
           .x %>%
              group_by(subgrp) %>%
              mutate(maxsubgrp = max(num), 
                     mingrpexclsubgrp = min(.$num[!.$subgrp %in% subgrp]), 
                     isless = maxsubgrp < mingrpexclsubgrp))
# A tibble: 9 x 6
# Groups:   subgrp [5]
#    grp subgrp   num maxsubgrp mingrpexclsubgrp isless
#  <int>  <int> <int>     <dbl>            <int> <lgl> 
#1     1      1     2         3                4 TRUE  
#2     1      1     3         3                4 TRUE  
#3     1      2     4         7                2 FALSE 
#4     1      2     6         7                2 FALSE 
#5     1      2     7         7                2 FALSE 
#6     2      3     7         7                6 FALSE 
#7     2      4     6         7                7 FALSE 
#8     2      4     7         7                7 FALSE 
#9     2      5     7         7                6 FALSE
```

---

Or use `unnest` after creating a `list` column

```
x %>%
  group_by(grp, subgrp) %>% 
  group_by(maxsubgrp = max(num), add = TRUE) %>%
  summarise(num = list(num))   %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>% 
  mutate(mingrpexclsubgrp = map_int(row_number(), ~ 
                                         num[-.x] %>%    
                                         unlist %>% 
                                         min)) %>% 
  unnest %>%
  mutate(isless = maxsubgrp < mingrpexclsubgrp)
# A tibble: 9 x 6
# Groups:   grp [2]
#    grp subgrp maxsubgrp mingrpexclsubgrp   num isless
#  <int>  <int>     <dbl>            <int> <int> <lgl> 
#1     1      1         3                4     2 TRUE  
#2     1      1         3                4     3 TRUE  
#3     1      2         7                2     4 FALSE 
#4     1      2         7                2     6 FALSE 
#5     1      2         7                2     7 FALSE 
#6     2      3         7                6     7 FALSE 
#7     2      4         7                7     6 FALSE 
#8     2      4         7                7     7 FALSE 
#9     2      5         7                6     7 FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is slightly different approach using `setdiff`

```
df %>%
    group_by(grp, subgrp) %>%
    mutate(
        maxsubgrp = max(num),
        num.subgrp = list(num)) %>%
    group_by(grp) %>%
    mutate(
        mingrpexclsubgrp = map_dbl(num.subgrp, function(x) {
            diff <- setdiff(num, x);
            if (length(diff) > 0) min(diff) else min(maxsubgrp) }),
        isless = maxsubgrp < mingrpexclsubgrp) %>%
    select(-num.subgrp)
## A tibble: 9 x 6
## Groups:   grp [2]
#    grp subgrp   num maxsubgrp mingrpexclsubgrp isless
#  <int>  <int> <int>     <dbl>            <dbl> <lgl>
#1     1      1     2        3.               4. TRUE
#2     1      1     3        3.               4. TRUE
#3     1      2     4        7.               2. FALSE
#4     1      2     6        7.               2. FALSE
#5     1      2     7        7.               2. FALSE
#6     2      3     7        7.               6. FALSE
#7     2      4     6        7.               7. FALSE
#8     2      4     7        7.               7. FALSE
#9     2      5     7        7.               6. FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x%>%
   group_by(grp,subgrp)%>%
   mutate(min=min(num))%>%
   group_by(grp)%>%
   mutate(min=max(min))%>%
   group_by(grp,subgrp)%>%
   mutate(isless=all(num<min))

# A tibble: 9 x 5
# Groups:   grp, subgrp [5]
    grp subgrp   num   min isless
  <int>  <int> <int> <dbl> <lgl> 
1     1      1     2     4 TRUE  
2     1      1     3     4 TRUE  
3     1      2     4     4 FALSE 
4     1      2     6     4 FALSE 
5     1      2     7     4 FALSE 
6     2      3     7     7 FALSE 
7     2      4     6     7 FALSE 
8     2      4     7     7 FALSE 
9     2      5     7     7 FALSE
```

To get the result as your table, we can do:

```
x%>%
  group_by(grp,subgrp)%>%
  mutate(min=min(num),maxsubgrp=max(num))%>%
  group_by(grp)%>%
  mutate(min1=max(min),min2=list(min))%>%
  group_by(grp,subgrp)%>%
  mutate(mingrpexclsubgrp=min(unlist(min2)[unlist(min2)!=min]),
         isless=all(num<min1))%>%
  select(-min,-min1,-min2)%>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 9 x 6
    grp subgrp   num maxsubgrp mingrpexclsubgrp isless
  <int>  <int> <int>     <dbl>            <dbl> <lgl> 
1     1      1     2         3                4 TRUE  
2     1      1     3         3                4 TRUE  
3     1      2     4         7                2 FALSE 
4     1      2     6         7                2 FALSE 
5     1      2     7         7                2 FALSE 
6     2      3     7         7                6 FALSE 
7     2      4     6         7                7 FALSE 
8     2      4     7         7                7 FALSE 
9     2      5     7         7                6 FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Summarizing by each row instead of mutate works correctly.

```
x %>%
# the key variable and generalizable answer
group_by(rownum = 1:n(),grp,subgrp,num) %>%
summarize(
  mingrpexclsubgrp = min(c(.$num)[.$grp == grp & .$subgrp != subgrp])
) %>%
# the rest of the variables
group_by(subgrp) %>%
mutate(maxsubgrp = max(num),
       isless = maxsubgrp < mingrpexclsubgrp)
```

I believe it can be further simplified:

```
x %>%
  group_by(subgrp) %>%
  mutate(
    # essentially ignores the grouping with .$ and uses custom grouping by comparison
    mingrpexclsubgrp = min(.$num[.$grp == grp[1] & .$subgrp != subgrp[1]]), # [1] prevent a warning where it chooses the first from >1 anyway
    maxsubgrp = max(num),
    isless = maxsubgrp < mingrpexclsubgrp
  )
```